# Android: Parsing JSON string inside of double quotes

Tags: java, android, json

I am normally using the following code to parse JSON strings:

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(message);
strmsg = jobj.getString("text");
```

when the data is like the below, it works great:

```
{"emailAddress": "testuser@gmail.com"}
```

All of a sudden, I am hitting issues when some other data came in. The parse failed and when I debugged, I found out that the string is like the below:

```
"{\"emailAddress\":\"testuser@gmail.com\”}"
```

Apparently, I am getting a JSON string that is inside of double quotes. 2 quick questions:
1)Is this normal, and should JSONObject be able to parse it?
2)If not, what's the recommended way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an error in the JSON generation. JSON should indeed throw  a parse error here. If you cannot change the way, the JSON string is generated, you need to clean it up manually. Remove the quotes around the curly braces and deescape the quotes (you could do it by simplay calling
    jsonString.replace("\\"", "\"");
while this looks convoluted, the escaping is necessary...

```
String test = "\"{\\\"emailAddress\\\":\\\"testuser@gmail.com\\\"}\"";
test.replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Comment: yup, this is exactly what I ended coding up. I was trying to avoid writing my own function and use the existing libraries. The other thing i had to do was the trim the front and the back quotes. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

to trim double quotes from both sides:

```
strmsg.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "")
```